# Sweaving #-Symbol

Tags: r, latex, sweave

How can I Sweave text with a #-sign?

Here, Sweaving and compiling is no problem:

```
<<echo=false,results=tex>>
cat("This is my text\n") 
@
```

But here, compiling gives an error:

```
<<echo=false,results=tex>>
cat("This is #my text\n")
@
```

The hash sign could not be compiled in tex. I have to set the Sweave option to "tex" because I want to print different text files in a loop and each text file should be separated by a new chapter.

```
<<results=tex>>
for(i in d){
  tx <- readLines(i)
  cat(tx, sep="\n")
  \chapter{i}
  }
```

Thanks for every hint.

TIM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape the hash-sign, since it has in LaTeX a special meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=false,results=tex>>=
cat("This is \\#my text\n") 
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: If you enter a second line in cat() you will see that in your example "\n" no longer works. There is no linebreak in the output pdf.

Comment: @Tim `cat("This is \\# my text\n
    This is \\# my text\n") ` worke for me: Two lines...

Comment: Really? Maybe I am doing something wrong, but for me it doesn`t work! Compiling works fine - but the PDF without linebreak!

Comment: However `cat("This is \\# my text \\\\ This is \\# my text\n")` or `cat("This is \\# my text \\newline This is \\# my text\n")` works. This was probably due to the results=tex - so we need to use tex-functions...